# Getting a single value from a JSON object using JSONPath

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have the following JSON and I need to get the plain `name` value using [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/):

```
{
  "single" : {
    "id" : 1, 
    "name" : "Item name"
  }
}
```

Expression that I used is `$.single.name` but I always get an array:

```
[ "Item name" ]
```

instead of a string value (`"Item name"`).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*but I always get an array:*

That is meant to happen. As you can read in [this documentation](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), under 'Result' (almost at the bottom):

> Please note, that the return value of jsonPath is an array, which is
>   also a valid JSON structure. So you might want to apply jsonPath to
>   the resulting structure again or use one of your favorite array
>   methods as sort with it.

So basically it will always return an array. If you need the data as an other type, e.g. a String in this case, you will have to do the conversion yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I got to that conclusion. Reason why I asked is to see if I am missing a bit of JSONPath syntax that will let me get the first element of the resulting array, and not an entire array.

Comment: @Ilija Sadly no. However I checked the source code and it's not very complicated, perhaps you could make some modifications to have it return something else than an array when you want it to.

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that (if path ends with ``~first`` it will return first element of the resulting array). Hate doing things like that, but if there was no other way…

Comment: If you got here like me you probably just need to add `[*]` to the end of your JSONPath query. It flattened the array being returned for me.

Comment: I'm using jsonpath-plus npm package that has `wrap` property. You can read more about the implications here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus#user-content-properties:~:text=section%20for%20details.)-,wrap%20(default,-%3A%20true)%20%2D%20Whether%20or

Answer (score 10):

I was using the [Java implementation](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) of JSONPath and got to the very same issue. What worked for me was to add '[0]' to the json path string. So in your case:

`$.single.name[0]`

Comment: I ran into the similar problem but with expression. I wan to get from array single object and from that object single value, but this doesnt work: `data[?(@.id==9617)][0].is_favorite` this doesnt work either `data[?(@.id==9617)].[0].is_favorite`

Comment: Provide an example of your data first.

Comment: Here it is `{state:{apiVersion:"V3_0",errorLevel:0,errorMessage:null,errorLink:null},data:[{id:94617,is_favorite:true,vip_sub_offers:[],vouchers:[{id:11613004,code:"F8JL2",offer:94617,subOffer:1613,validTo:"2016-05-20T23:59:59.000",state:"USED",stateCode:2,obtainType:"NORMAL",redirectUrl:null,phoneNumber:null,messageText:null,shopId:94614,assignTime:"2016-05-19T00:00:03.000",useTime:"2016-05-19T00:00:05.000"}]}]}`

Comment: The Java implementation can't apply the [0] after using a predicate expression. It's apparently out of spec:
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/272

Comment: As far as is read somewhere, there is a Java implementation in fastjason, that can handle the [0]. The implementation from Jayway can't.

Answer (score 3):

It depends of the library implementations in which some of them are rigid and others offer an option to make the developer smile.

### Nodejs

For example in nodejs there is a npm module   : https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath

Which have a method called **value**, which does exactly what we need

**jp.value(obj, pathExpression[, newValue])**

> Returns the value of the **first element** matching pathExpression. If newValue is provided, sets the value of the first matching element and returns the new value.

### Java

```
String json = "...";
Object document = ...parse(json);
String author0 = JsonPath.read(document, "$.store.book[0].author");
```

As you can see **author0** is a string, not an array

Source: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Answer (score 1):

In case you got this error

> "Unable to get a scalar value for expression $.yourfield"

You have just to configure the ***EvaluateJsonPath*** processor by changing the return type property value to **'json'** instead of **'auto-detect'**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In an Azure Bicep template, `value` worked for me, in extracting a single parameter from a jsonc parameter file:  `$.parameters.aksAgentPoolIdentityPrincipalId.value`

One could fathom a guess that in my case this is used as the implementation:
https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath