# how to remove [] character at extracted json using json path

Tags: json, jsonpath

```
{
    "responseCode": "200",
    "data": {
        "sequence": 1,
        "used": true,
        "sensingTags": [
            {
                "code": "LED",
                "value": 1,
                "updatedOn": 1587557350251
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My goal is get updatedOn value from this json using jsonPath like this

```
1587557350251
```

i thought below jsonPath will work but it extract only empty list.

```
$..sensingTags[?(@.code == 'LED')][0].updatedOn
```

And i want to know how to extract value like below

```
            {
                "code": "LED",
                "value": 1,
                "updatedOn": 1587557350251
            }
```

Not like this one.

```
[
   {
      "code" : "LED",
      "value" : 1,
      "updatedOn" : 1587557350251
   }
]
```

Comment: can you add some code to generate this JSON?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Getting a single value from a JSON object using JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608050/getting-a-single-value-from-a-json-object-using-jsonpath), JsonPath will always return an array (or a `false`) at that point...

Best you can do is process it as an array of updatedOn and simply always grab the first value.

```
$..sensingTags[?(@.code == 'LED')].updatedOn
```