# JSON path evaluation inside JSON path expression

Tags: jsonpath

I've got this very simple json :

```
{
    "authors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Douglas Adams"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "John Doe"
        }
    ],
    "books": [
        {
            "name": "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy",
            "author_id": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to request the name of the author of "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy".
I've tried this JSON path but it doesn't work:

```
$.authors[?(@.id == $.books[?(@.name == "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy")].author_id)].name
```

All online tools I tried indicate a syntax error which seems due to the presence of a JSON path inside my filter.

Could anyone please help me figure out what's wrong and what is the right syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you running this filter

```js
$.books[?(@.name == "The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy")].author_id
```

it returns **an array** instead of a value:

```json
[
  1
]
```

Syntax error occurs when you pass an array to compare with the value of `id`:

```js
$.authors[?(@.id == {the array value}].author_id)].name
```

However, you may not be able to extract the value using JSONPath, depends on the language you are using. See [Getting a single value from a JSON object using JSONPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608050/getting-a-single-value-from-a-json-object-using-jsonpath)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Bemn
I'm going to see whether I can fetch the first value of the array with the jsonpath implementation I use.